# How to make an object follow the mouse on plane/floor with ease/delay in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-three-fiber

This is already working perfectly:

```
const [dist, cycle] = useReducer((x) => (x % 4) + 1, 20);
useFrame(({ raycaster }) => {
    if (ref?.current) {
        raycaster?.ray?.at(dist, ref?.current?.position);
    }
});
```

live demo:
https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-mouse-to-world-elh73?file=/src/index.js:311-315

how could I add a small delay to the animation so that the object is not immediately at the mouse position? and how could I add an offset, so it is not at the center of the mouse?

Answer (score 1):

Like always, it was me, I did it.

```
useFrame(({ raycaster }) => {
    const mouse = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    if (ref?.current) {
        //inject the raycast intersect point into mouse vec3
        raycaster?.ray?.at(dist, mouse);
        //get the object temp position
        const myPos = new Vector3(
            ref?.current?.position.x,
            ref?.current?.position.y,
            ref?.current?.position.z
        );
        //calculate the distance between mouse and object
        mouse.sub(myPos);
        //do the ease thing here, the higher the more ease
        mouse.divideScalar(10);
        //sumup:
        myPos.add(mouse);
        ref?.current?.position.set(myPos.x, myPos.y, myPos.z);
    }
});
```